# How to get values from one module to another in gradle java project?

Tags: java, gradle, getter-setter

I created two modules in my project.

I want to get value from one module to another module.

[my project's github link](https://github.com/Jeevasimba/connection_between_two_modules_in_java)

In my first module :

```
package org.example;

public class Main {

    static String c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    c = "hai";
    while (true){

    }
    }

    public String geta(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

In my second module :

```
package org.p;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.example.Main a = new org.example.Main();
        System.out.println(a.geta());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
null
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oETNg.png)

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `while (true){` is an infinite loop, it will never complete.  It's not directly causing your problem, but I don't understand why you would use it.

Comment: first , I run my first module then I run the second one . so , I used while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rather strange, I don't know what you are trying to do.  Maybe a more complete example will clarify the issue.  For an immediate answer, you could use static initialization here.

```
package org.example;

public class Main {

    static String c = "hai";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public String geta(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

To access a field that is initialized by a method, you must call the method first.  Don't put infinite loops or bad code in those methods, they won't finish.

```
package org.p;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.example.Main a = new org.example.Main();
        a.main(null);
        System.out.println(a.geta());
    }
}
```

The new class:

```
package org.example;

public class Main {

    private static String c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       c  = "hai";
    }

    public String geta(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: no , I want to set the value from main method.

Comment: Well, first, don't put an infinite loop in a method you intend to call.  Why do that?

Comment: please saw my project in github repo then only you understand this problem. I have two modules in gradle project. repo link : https://github.com/Jeevasimba/connection_between_two_modules_in_java